# How to push multiple objects in array angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have form which contain two text field and button.

I want when i enter values in form and click on save button, it will display inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addStaticValues(){  
    const conditionObj = {};    
    const conditionArr = [];
    const formData = this.aValues.vForm.value;
    if(formData.parameter_value.length > 0 && formData.label_value.length > 0) {
      conditionObj['parameter_value'] = formData.parameter_value;
      conditionObj['label_value'] = formData.label_value;
      conditionArr.push(conditionObj);
    }     
  }
```

you are reinitializing const conditionArr = [] every time (on each click).  declare conditionArr  as global.

Answer (score 0):

const conditionArr should be outside the function as it was getting initialized every time to empty array.

```
const conditionArr = [];
    addStaticValues(){  
        const conditionObj = {};   
        
        const formData = this.aValues.vForm.value;
        if(formData.parameter_value.length > 0 && formData.label_value.length > 0) {
          conditionObj['parameter_value'] = formData.parameter_value;
          conditionObj['label_value'] = formData.label_value;
          conditionArr.push(conditionObj);
        }     
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `const conditionArr = []` outside the function which handles the saving. Otherwise the array is redeclared every time you save.